# how to load xml data from server in client side using javascript or vbscript?

Tags: javascript, xml, vbscript

It's been almost three weeks and I'm Googling around. my eyes got tired and headaches was included too.
I couldn't do it what even 8-10 hours daily computing :(
I have some data that saved in a valid XML file on the server(domain or sub-domain)

I've choosed XML because I'm may or probably need it for other future application use.

What I want to do is:
1- including the XML file and load it on a client side HTML page.(does sub-domain or normal domain make a difference while including?)
2- I do prefer using JavaScript (or Vb Script) or any other client side script(if available) for parsing or manipulating thing.

**And If you do prefer me a better way to include a server side XML file including....I'm listening**

**EDIT:**
I'm working on AJAX now but why I can't get data from a URL?
something like:
    xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.mywebsite.com/xmlfile.xml",true);
buy it's not working :(

Comment: you might need to show us your full AJAX code, what the result is and what you expect to see.

Comment: take a look at [W3Schools AJAX example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) you can see there's an example about getting out data from an XML file which is located on the server.my problem is the URL of requested XML file...I can't show the XML file as text as above example but in client side while the file is **on server** I tried but it was hopeless

Comment: The [file in the example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_info.txt) is not an XML file, it's a text file that contains a HTML snippet `<p>AJAX is not a new programming language.</p>
<p>AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.</p>`

Comment: are you running your AJAX query across domains? it's likely your browser will not allow this due to security issues

Comment: I know it's not a XML file! it's just a similar way to my problem
I'm using it in Windows 7 sidebar gadget(I think it uses ActiveX object same as IE)
and I request the file from an URL looks something like this `http://www.mywebsite.com/xmlfile.xml` in a regular HTML file that includes AJAX requests same as the link I described above.

Comment: i still think you need to show _your_ code

Comment: I am using **that** code snippet! because I don't have any other idea :( any suggestion or recommending some way is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't given the *actual code that you're using*, I am guessing here and have put together an HTA that you can try. This only works on Windows (as I believe that is the platform you're targeting). Copy this code into a text file and save it with a `.hta` file extension:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTA Ajax Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxRequest = function() {
                var http = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
                http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                        var div = document.getElementById('target-div');
                        div.innerHTML = http.responseText;
                    }
                }
                http.open('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_info.txt', true);
                http.send();
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target-div"></div>
        <input type="button" value="load" onclick="ajaxRequest();"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

On clicking the Load button, the text from your w3schools example will be loaded into the page. This should get you started. Should you want to provide a cross-platform solution, a library like jQuery will handle all the differences for you.

As mentioned before, the url used in the request is a full url to a resource on a different server. This won't work if you put this code on a server because of the cross-domain security issue.

If you want to pick up information from an XML file, you might want to use `http.responseXML` rather than `http.responseText`. The former property makes the response available as an XML document object rather than a text string.

Comment: I AM using your code now :) and where does HTML application came from?!! :O....thanks Mr...uh.....Oracle certified profession! that's exactly what I want BUT can I use it (or include it) in a regular HTML file?

Comment: you can use this in a regular HTML file, but 1. it's not cross-browser (internet explorer only) and 2. when you put your HTML file on a server, the browser will prevent you from accessing the ajax_info.txt file because it's on a different server. Using AJAX, you can only access resources that reside on the same server  as the one that serves your web page (ie on the same domain)

Comment: yeah I know something about both cross browser and origin policy.but as I mentioned before I just use it locally(client-side) not on the server! I still need to get the data but in a HTML file (not HTA) because Win 7 gadget's only open the HTML file.I tried with HTA but it doesn't function with this file type(only HTML allowed). so is there's anyway? RSS feed's are great but I'm not sure to use it because it's standards.

Answer (score 0):

> including the xml file and load it on a client side html page.

Use Ajax, and [use a library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to access it.

> does sub-domain or normal domain make a difference while including?

If it is different to the page: [yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: can I not to use J Query? just using a pure Ajax?

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery, [other libraries are available](http://microjs.com/#ajax). You *should* use a library as (a) there are fiddly differences between browsers to deal with and (b) the syntax to play with XHR directly is ugly.

Comment: well, thanks for both both of you.you've cleared things out for me.Quentin you look you've done a lot's of test and have skills in XHR...what do you recommend to me?

Comment: I don't have any strong preference for any one library over another. jQuery is close to ubiquitous so isn't a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use AJAX? http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: I agree with Quentin about jQuery. It is a good library, but I think it is better for beging to play with XHR directly. It is uglier, but you will learn more.